# Analyze Sound Ahead of Time - Actionscript

Tags: audio, actionscript

I would like to create a game that would analyze an mp3 a few seconds ahead of where it is playing live. A basic idea would be similar to guitar hero, the 'frets' you can see coming and prepare, then they hit and sync with the song in real time.

Is there a way to analyze a Sound file ahead of time, or analyze a muted Sound file?

Answer (score 1):

You can get access to the underlying audio data with Sound.extract(). You can also feed samples to a Sound object dynamically by adding a SampleDataEvent listener to it and playing it without providing it with an mp3.

So essentially the process usually looks like this:

1. Load an mp3 into a Sound object.
2. Extract some or all of its sample data into a ByteArray so that you can analyze/modify it. Depending on what you need to do, you may just extract enough at a time to keep ahead of the output by the amount you want.
3. Create a second Sound object for output - don't provide this one with an mp3. Add a listener to it for SampleDataEvents and then play it. It will dispatch SampleDataEvents regularly as it needs more audio (it takes 2048, 4096, or 8192 samples at a time, 44100 being one second's worth). Each time you get a SampleDataEvent, you populate its data ByteArray property with the samples you want it to play next.

While I don't understand exactly what it is you're trying to do, it sounds like you'd keep your extraction process going a couple seconds ahead of your playback process - extracting to a buffer ByteArray, doing your analysis, and then copying samples from the beginning of that buffer BA every time the output Sound requests more samples.